# if else not working in statement C++

Tags: c++11

How would I get an else statement that says incorrect color if they don't choose from one of the options? I tried an if else and an else but it would show up at the end of my code even if the colors had the correct options.

I'm a newbie... Thanks for the help.

```
enter code here

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string color1, color2;
    string Red, Blue, Yellow;

    cout << "When you enter two primary colors, I will tell you\n";
    cout << "what color they make when they are mixed together.\n\n";
    cout << "Enter red, blue, or yellow: \n" << endl;
    getline(cin, color1);

    if (color1 == "red" || color1 == "Red")
    {
        cout << "Please choose from blue or yellow:\n";
        getline(cin, color2);

        if (color2 == "yellow" ||color2 == "Yellow")
        {
            cout << "\nGreat you make Orange.\n";
        }
        if (color2 == "Blue" || color2 == "blue")
        {
            cout << "\nGreat you make purple.\n";
        }
    }


    if (color1 == "yellow" || color1 == "Yellow")
    {
        cout << "Please choose from blue or red:\n";
        getline(cin, color2);

        if (color2 == "red" || color2 == "Red")
        {
            cout << "\nGreat you make Orange.\n";
        }
        if (color2 == "Blue" || color2 == "blue")
        {
            cout << "\nGreat you make Green.\n";
        }
    }

    if (color1 == "Blue" || color1 == "blue")
    {
        cout << "Please choose from yellow or red:\n";
        getline(cin, color2);

        if (color2 == "red" || color2 == "Red")
        {
            cout << "\nGreat you make Purple.\n";
        }
        if (color2 == "yellow" || color2 == "Yellow")
        {
            cout << "\nGreat you make Green.\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

    enter code here
```

Comment: you use `else`.

Comment: Connect your 3 if clauses with "else if"s then you can have an else at the end. But honestly, go grab a book on C++, control flow like if else should be explained in the first chapter if not first 10 pages.

Comment: I use else after the last embedded if and it shows up in the code for even correct submissions. How would you write it in the first block of code?

Comment: makes sense, thanks for the help.